# How do I add nodes at index in Java?

Tags: java, addition

```
public void addAtIndex(int payload, int index) throws AmishException
{
    if(index == 0)
    {
        this.addFront(payload);
    }
    else if(index == this.length()-1)
    {
        this.addEnd(payload);
    }
    else if(index < this.numberOfElements || index > this.length()-1)
    {
        throw new AmishException("LinkedList Error: Index: " + index + " is out of bound!!!");
    }
    else 
    {
    }
}
```

I have four classes in total, they can add nodes to the front and end without a problem, but I can't seem to figure out how to add them at an index. I have a method that determines length but after two hours I can't figure it out. This is the method that will add at index, but all it does now is throw an exception and adds to front and back.

Comment: the else if(index >= 0) isn't supposed to be in there sorry about that.

Comment: You can edit your question to remove it

Comment: possible duplicate of [insert new node at any index within a single linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919996/insert-new-node-at-any-index-within-a-single-linked-list)

Comment: The above link is for c, but the answer just describes the logic, not the actual code.

Comment: I need something that adds it at an index, whether it be a new method or something within the else statement

Comment: Use a count like that answer I linked suggested and iterate through your list until you reach your count. You can create a new method or add an else statement. I would suggest adding a new method though as it is easier to reuse.

Comment: I made a loop in a new  method that runs through the number of items or .length. Then did a if(i == index) how do I make it so it adds a new node at that index?

Comment: I'm curious - what is an AmishException (aside from the historical decision about working children), and how does it differ from other exceptions?

Comment: It was just an example used in my class, he was just showing us how to create new exceptions that's all, all it does is say index is out of bounds if the place I try to place the node in is above the number of items