# 2 element array list in C

Tags: c, arrays, list

I'm trying to get a list of integers indexed, i.e. I put in aab I get 97 97 98 and I want each of these indexed as in a regular array.

```
typedef struct element {   
    struct element *next;
    int value;
    int index;
} listElements;
```

thing is when I assign `pointer -> index = integer; integer++` and then `printf` it, the value column is printed just as it should be `a a b` but the index column prints `2 0 1`. where did I go wrong?

edit: more code

```
int addToList ( listElements *list, int character, int integer ) {
    listElements *pointer, *element;
    pointer = list;

    while ( pointer -> next != NULL ) {
        pointer = pointer -> next;
    }

    element = ( listElements* ) malloc ( sizeof ( listElements ) );
    element -> value = character;
    element -> index = integer;
    integer++;
    element -> next = NULL;
    pointer -> next = NULL;

    return integer;
}

void printList ( listElements *list ) {
    listElements *pointer = list;

    while ( pointer != 0 ) {
        printf ( "%d %d\n", pointer -> value, pointer -> index );
        pointer = pointer -> next;
    }
}


int main () {

    char character;

    first = ( listElements* ) malloc ( sizeof ( listElements ) );
    first -> value = character = getchar ();
    first -> index = 0;
    first -> next = NULL;


    while ( ( character = getchar () ) != 'Q' ) {
        first -> index = addToList ( first, character, first -> index );
    }

    printList ( first );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not a clue what you are asking.  What is "aab"?  Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Show the code that constructs the list.

Comment: Your code shows no printing.  Where are your printing values?

Comment: Are you attempting to write a dyamically sized list? Read up on linked lists and I think this was already answered once (at least): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19919996/insert-new-node-at-any-index-within-a-single-linked-list

Comment: do you want the index to be 97 if the character is 'a' ?

Comment: no I want the index to be an array like index so for aab I get pairs { a, 0 } { a, 1 } { b, 2 } but the code given results in { a, 2 } { a, 0 } { b, 1 }. actually with integer ascii values of the characters

Comment: That's not surprising, because your `while` loop is effectively incrementing the index of the first element each time. Before the `while` loop, `first->index` is `0`. After two iterations it is `2`. (The value is incremented in the `addToList` function which is returning the passed in value plus 1.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index is not right (2 0 1 instead of 0 1 2. If that is what you are asking) because you are doing this:

```
first -> index = addToList ( first, character, first -> index );
```

You are assigning the return value to first element's index.

Change it to something like below:

```
int index = 1; // declare at right position in main.
while ( ( character = getchar () ) != 'Q' )
{
    index = addToList ( first, character, index );
}
```

Comment: thank you! it's still strange for me that it assigned values correctly up to a shift, but at least it works now.